# 6 ruby processes calling SHOW TABLES on mysql, bringing mysql down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I am running a Rails 3.1.0 app and I have an odd problem. On our staging server, with VERY little activity we have 5 ruby processes CONSTANTLY pinging mySQL with the following:

```
poll([{fd=12, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
write(12, "\f\0\0\0\3SHOW TABLES", 16)  = 16
select(13, [12], NULL, NULL, NULL)      = 1 (in [12])
read(12, "\1\0\0\1\1D\0\0\2\3def\0\vTABLE_NAMES\0\31Tabl"..., 16384) = 637
poll([{fd=12, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
write(12, "\f\0\0\0\3SHOW TABLES", 16)  = 16
select(13, [12], NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

That last line is incomplete, but we're talking a few times every single second (x5/6 processes). The server is a beast, it has 32GB of RAM and has been optimised somewhat (the mySQL setup that is) but its killing the server.

Like I say, the server has very little activity, so its not users, or a task.

(For admins thinking of moving this away from this forum, I believe this is a ruby/rails issue, I'm not sure if it was in a server forum it would have a good compatibility with answerers)

I would be incredibly grateful for any advice, I fear it might be a bit over my head. I'm not such a Linux/mySQL pro.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have delayed-job (or similar) running?

Comment: hi mu, we (usually) have resque running, but I have killed the process. The aforementioned ruby processes are however still there. The tasks we did have resque run were very intensive, we have 1m products that we "do stuff to" regularly, but that as of right this moment is not running and we still have the active processes. The (empty) resque workers were killed 24 hours ago, and the tables that would be active if anything was happening, are not.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the connection pool for your database.  Does running this help?

ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!

Specifically, in your config/database.yml for this environment, try setting  pool:  50 and restart rails, then see if this affects the result. The next question if your pool is exhausted would be to get to the specifics of why the database connection pool is getting used up (this command, or something running in resque).  I think the pool default size is 4 or 5

Comment: Hi ebeland, thanks for your suggestion. I'm going to try those out. Interestingly, I restarted the server - my colleague thinks I'm crazy thinking it would help, but I wanted to clear any memory etc etc (I'm no server expert!) - anyway, it was fine for a while, load average at 0.17 and my problem wasn't happening, then all of a sudden, boom. Back up to 90% CPU for mysql and SHOW TABLES flying in. I'm looking at the logs, and nothing is happening, no resque workers running.

Comment: I misunderstood your issue. I thought you meant you had some workers doing that activity intentionally. My suggestion may help with the problem of this small amount of activity killing the machine, but not with why these queries are there in the first place.  Sorry.